# ODBC scalar function for UTC timestamp?

Tags: sql, odbc, timestamp, utc

Question:

The following ODBC sequence

```
{fn NOW()}
```

returns the current timestamp in localtime.

Is there any ODBC scalar function that returns the current timestamp in UTC ?

**And note:**
   **ODBC** function, not just any vendor-specific function like GETUTCDATE.

Comment: Here is the API appendix for functions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711813(v=vs.85).aspx and it seems you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am interested in the same problem but it seems the answer is No - ODBC cannot tell you current UTC.